# Tcl how to use file attributes command to change permissions?

Tags: file, tcl

I want to set [file attributes](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm#M7), when user double clicks the file it is open (by default) in write mode, I would like to change that to read-only.

```
set f [open "mydata.csv" a+]
file attributes "mydata.csv" -readonly
```

When running this, the attributes of the file are the same. There's no X or V next to read-only.

[image]

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also pass the value to set that attribute to, or you'll just be reading the value (that's a common Tcl idiom). In this case, the `-readonly` attribute is boolean valued, so you'd do this to enable it:

```
file attributes "mydata.csv" -readonly true
```

And to disable it, you'd do:

```
file attributes "mydata.csv" -readonly false
```

(You can use anything that Tcl interprets as a boolean; `1`, `on`, and `yes` all are aliases for `true`, and `0`, `off`, and `no` are all aliases for `false`.)